# Как сделать редирект неавторизованных пользователей на две главных страницы?

Tags: php, yii2

в web.php создал `'bootstrap' => ['log','MyInit'],`
далее инициализировал `'components' => [
        'MyInit' => [
            'class' => 'app\components\MyInit'
        ],`
Ну и далее проблема:

```
class MyInit  extends Component  {

public function init() {
    if (Yii::$app->getUser()->isGuest && Yii::$app->getRequest()->url == ('/loginsms'))
    {
        Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(array('site/login'));
    }
    elseif (Yii::$app->getUser()->isGuest && Yii::$app->getRequest()->url !== ('/login') )
    {
        Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(array('site/loginsms'));
    }

    parent::init();
}
```

}
На главной странице есть ссылка на /loginsms где есть только поле ввода. Так вот в описанном случае работает только редирект на /login. Как заставить сделать условие "если гость и ссылка не loginsms (либо любая другая)) - то редирект на логин. Если гость и запрошенная ссылка loginsms - то ее и отображать?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю правильней будет проверять, авторизирован пользователь, или нет, в контроллере, и соответственно, для экшинов, где авторизация не нужна, не делать эту проверку

Comment: Авторизация нужна абсолютно всегда, поэтому, чтобы не забыть делать проверки на каждый экшн, вынесено отдельным компонентом в конфиг. И это как раз и есть проверка на гостя, с редиректом на страницу авторизации. Только страниц авторизации две: по логину/паролю и другая страница по смс.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - сделайте весь логин на одной странице. Переключение между "sms" и "не sms" в виде вкладок. Остальная обработка - javascript'ом.